# What is the process for bounties being returned to a user when an adequate answer hasn't been given?

Tags: support

I recently created a bounty on a question, that I feel did not get an adequate answer. There were a couple of attempts (and I appreciate the effort). However it wasn't adequately answered. The bounty timeline ended, yet the bounty (350) wasn't returned. I see that if an answer receives 2 or more vote, but is not an appropriate answer, half is given, in this case, none received enough votes to make that happen? Link to question [Help with Geocoding and Openlayers missing markers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3896/help-with-geocoding-and-openlayers-missing-markers)

Answer (score 4):

As reported in the [FAQ](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/faq):

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days, the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with at least 2 upvotes will be awarded half the bounty amount.
>
> In any case, you will always give up the amount of reputation specified in the bounty, so if you start a bounty, be sure to follow up and award your bounty to the best answer!

Who offers a bounty doesn't get back the reputation offered for the bounty, even in the case he didn't select any question to which give the bounty.